# Why is spark library using outputs(i+1) in MultilayerPerceptron for previous Delta Calculations

Tags: apache-spark, neural-network, apache-spark-mllib, backpropagation, feed-forward

Looking at [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/ann/Layer.scala#L541) code

```
for (i <- (L - 2) to (0, -1)) {
    layerModels(i + 1).computePrevDelta(deltas(i + 1), outputs(i + 1), deltas(i))
}
```

I want to understand why are we passing `outputs(i+1)` instead of `outputs(i)` in the code snippet above. As far as I understand this is only needed for sigmoid activation layer which has a derivative as `f'(x) = f(x) * (1-f(x)) = outputs(i) * (1-outputs(i))`

Which means in order to find prevDelta we should be using `outputs(i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured why it is so. I will answer here if someone like me stumbles here by chance.

You have to notice that we are calculating delta for layer i which only depends on next (i+1 th) layer's delta and gradient. You have to notice that we are using `layerModels(i + 1)` as needed and not `layerModels(i)`